# Equation 5.39 in "Introduction to Quantum Mechanics" by Griffiths

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, atomic-physics, fermions

Section 5.2.1 of the book "Introduction to Quantum Mechanics" by Griffiths and Schroeter (Third edition) gives a simple model for a helium atom. It assumes the nucleus is stationary, and ignores the forces between the electrons. Also, spin interactions, relativistic corrections and the finite size of the nucleus are not taken into account. Now they deduce in Equation 5.39 that the state of the two electrons can be written as the product of their individual states:
$$\psi(\mathbf{r_1},\mathbf{r_2})=\psi_{nlm}(\mathbf{r_1})\psi_{n'l'm'}(\mathbf{r_2}).$$
However, both electrons are fermions. According to Equation 5.17, the two-particle state should be:
$$\psi_-(\mathbf{r_1},\mathbf{r_2})=A[\psi_a(\mathbf{r_1})\psi_b(\mathbf{r_2})-\psi_b(\mathbf{r_1})\psi_a(\mathbf{r_2})].$$
Why does Equation 5.39 seem to assume that the two electrons are distinguishable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Helium two particle system of identical particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/308149/)

Comment: Yes, thank you!